# Jetty Classloading issue

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jndi

I'm using the jetty maven plugin to run a webapp locally and I'm getting a class cast exception when I try to pull in a JNDI resource.

I have a jetty config with a resource object, which is a configuration bean that is utilized via JNDI. This class resides in a different jar on the classpath that is in the lib directory:

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg>config/MyConfigObject</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="my.config.ConfigObject">
                <Set name="foo">bar</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

This is retrieved via Spring:

```
<bean id="MyConfigObject" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/config/MyConfigObject" />
</bean>
```

Inside of a servlet, I'm grabbing the object manually:

```
final MyConfigObject config = (MyConfigObject) applicationContext.getBean("MyConfigObject");
```

But when I try to access the servlet, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.config.MyConfigObject cannot be cast to my.config.MyConfigObject
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to class loading, but I'm not 100% certain. MyConfigObject's class loader is the default sun class loader, while the thread's current class loader is jetty's `WebAppClassLoader`. My jar is in WEB-INF/lib, and I've even added it manually to extraClasspath in the maven plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.25</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jettyConfig>${basedir}/test/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <extraClasspath>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}/WEB-INF/lib/myConfigJar-1.0.jar</extraClasspath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>testing</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myConfigJar</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I'm kind of stuck at this point. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've got the jar listed in too many places - you attempts to add it to `extraClasspath` will actually make it worse, not better.

You say it's in `WEB-INF/lib`, but I assume it's also listed as a dependency in your `pom.xml`

You don't want to do that, you need to have 1 single reference to it. Either as a dependency in your `pom.xml` or in your `lib` directory, or in `extraClasspath`, but only in 1 place.

*(Hint: `pom.xml` is almost certainly the right place, get rid of the others)*

Comment: That sounds promising. I threw all kinds of jars at jetty to attempt to fix it. It's a project dependency, a plugin dependency, it's in the lib folder, and included in extraClasspath. I'll try that.

Comment: It's been awhile since I looked at this, but I got it working by only having a plugin dependency on the jar, and either removing the dependency from the pom (and essentially lib since that's how my war is built) or setting the dependency scope to provided.

Answer (score 0):

your webapp should *not* include the "my.config.MyConfigObject" class (and related classes) in it.

the underlying problem is that you are getting the class loaded by 2 different classloaders.  you need to eliminate the class from your webapp classloader so that your webapp will use the same class that jetty is using.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 'include' means? The class isn't a part of the webapp project. It's in a dependent project that is on the classpath.

Comment: nothing in the webapp itself should reference the jar.  it should only be on jetty's classpath.